# How to shorten this code in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a query code to extract a list of values, and out of it I want the minimum value.

```
 IEnumerable<string> i = from c in Data
                    where c.CompletionPercentage < 360
                    select  c;

 decimal ds = i.Min(c=> c.GoalId);
```

How can we combine these codes in a single line? Syntactic sugar code using lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var ds=Data.Where(d=>d.CompletionPercentage < 360).Min(c=> c.GoalId);
```

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it solved your issue, it helps the community :)

Comment: You're welcome. I saw now that you are a new member of SO, welcome ;). If you think my answer help you to solve your issue, please consider mark your question as answered by clicking the check-mark.There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
decimal ds = Data.Where(c => c.CompletionPercentage < 360).Min(c => c.GoalId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same that:

```
var ds = (from c in Data where c.CompletionPercentage < 360 select c).Min(c => c.GoalId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal ds = Data.Where(c => c.CompletionPercentage < 360).Min(c => c.GoalId);
```

Here you get a list of the objects with CompletionPercentage < 360

```
Data.Where(c => c.CompletionPercentage < 360)
```

Then get min value of them based on GoalId

```
.Min(c => c.GoalId)
```

I hope this description helps.